# Pointy bezier curve created with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I played around with vanilla JavaScript and SVG for the first time.
Now I am at a point where I can't solve the issue myself.

The idea was to move points on their y-axis.
The x-axis is given by already existing points (red circles).

I now calculate an isosceles triangle which is centered at the x value of the cursor. The triangle moves along with the mouse.
Now the intersection of the given points (red circles) with the triangle is calculated.
At this intersection points are set. Trough these points I draw a bezier curve.

The idea behind the triangle is that I don't want to create a very "steep" curve when the red dots are further apart. So I can "spread it out" / flatten the curve a bit. At least that's the idea.

The basics are working fine so far but a strange thing occurs: In two points (marked in blue) the curve looks like the simulated triangle - but all points in between create a perfect bezier-curve.

I can't figure out what's going on.
Would highly appreciate any input - please be kind with my (probably) bad code - I am a beginner. ;)

Thanks!

CodePen: https://codepen.io/clmsvie/pen/Edqzpp?editors=1111

```js
var n = 0;

c1x = 50;
d = 350;

var gap = 100;

var dotsX = [];
var dotsXY = [];

// Kreise zeichnen
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");

for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  circle.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "blub c" + i);
  circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", c1x);
  circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", d);
  circle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 15);
  svg.appendChild(circle);
  dotsX.push(c1x); // Werte der Punkte ins Array schreiben
  dotsXY.push(c1x);
  c1x += gap;
}

// Dreieck zeichnen, entlang der virtuellen x Achse
var $tri = document.querySelectorAll(".triangle");

ta = 100; // Strecke = Höhe
tc = 250; // Strecke = Distanz x-Achse
tB = 350; // Punkt = X Punkt der Maus

ax = tB - tc; // A
ay = d;
bx = tB; // B
by = d;
cx = tB; //C
cy = d - ta;

// Maus Koordinaten feststellen

function mouseMove(e) {
  x = typeof e.pageX != "undefined" ? e.pageX : e.touches[0].pageX;
  y = typeof e.pageY != "undefined" ? e.pageY : e.touches[0].pageY;

  //console.log("x = " + x + " y = " + y);

  // Punkt entlang b Achse eines Rechtwinkligen Dreiecks verschieben

  tB = x;

  ax = x - tc; // A
  ay = d;
  bx = x; // B
  by = d;
  cx = x; //C
  cy = d - ta;

  setDots();
}

"mousemove touchmove".split(" ").forEach(function(e) {
  document.addEventListener(e, mouseMove, true);
});

function setDots() {
  // ### Rote Kreise auf Dreieck setzen

  // 2. Brechne neue Höhe der Punkte (auf Dreieck)

  var dotsXY = dotsX.map(function(dotX) {
    tA = tB - tc;
    disDotInTri = dotX < tB ? dotX - tA : tB + tc - dotX;
    dotY = d - disDotInTri * ta / tc;
    dotY = dotY <= d ? dotY : d; // Nicht negativ werden
    return [dotX, dotY.toFixed(2)];
  });

  //console.log("Y-Werte: " + dotsXY);

  var path =
    "M0," +
    d +
    " C" +
    dotsXY
      .map(function(dot) {
        return dot[0] + "," + dot[1];
      })
      .join(" ");

  console.log(path);
  console.log(dotsXY[0] + " - " + dotsXY[2] + " - " + dotsXY[4]);

  // Kontrollpunkte

  var paras = document.getElementsByClassName("kontrolle");

  while (paras[0]) {
    paras[0].parentNode.removeChild(paras[0]);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < dotsXY.length; i++) {
    var circleKontrolle = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "circle"
    );
    circleKontrolle.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "blub kontrolle");
    circleKontrolle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", dotsXY[i][0]);
    circleKontrolle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", dotsXY[i][1]);
    circleKontrolle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 5);
    svg.appendChild(circleKontrolle);
  }

  document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("d", path);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:#d1ff88;
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

.blub {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  fill: red;
}

#bezier-path {
  stroke: red;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.2;
}

.c2, .c5 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg class="test">
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="red" fill="none" id="bezier-path" stroke-width="1.2" d="M0,350 C50,333.20 150,293.20 250,253.20 350,286.80 450,326.80 550,350.00 650,350.00 750,350.00 850,350.00"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The kinks happen between 2 Bézier curves. Try using the C command only the first time. Then use the S command. This will connect your curves smoothly.

Comment: @enxaneta, thanks a lot. It never occurred to me that the curve could be the issue instead of my javascript. Tired brain ;-) Thanks a lot again!